# Certbot detects incorrect Common Name (CN)

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have multiple virtual hosts on the same server using CentOS 6. After running `sudo ./path/to/certbot-auto --apache` I have successfully installed a certificate for a website `https://domain1.example`. Browser confirms that the certificate is issued to Common Name (CN) `domain1.example`.

However, after repeating the same procedure for `domain2.example`, browser is warning that the connection is not secure and the certificate is issued to Common Name `192.168.1.5`, which is a local IP address of the server. Why isn't the Common Name correctly determined for `domain2.example`? What could be the reason?

Without `https://` the website `http://domain2.example` is working properly.

Comment: It seems the second certificate was produced with `192.168.1.5` as Common Name instead of `domain2.example`. But this is offtopic for a programming related website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was due to the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file which enables SSL for Apache. Since CentOS loads all Apache conf files in alphabetical order, only those conf files will be using SSL which come after `ssl.conf` in alphabetical order. All files that come before will not be recognized for SSL.

In my case conf file for `domain1.example` came after `ssl.conf` and thus was recognized for SSL. But the conf file for `domain2.example` was before `ssl.conf` and therefore was ignored. A simple renaming `ssl.conf` to `000-ssl.conf` put that file on top of the list and all the other files were loaded correctly.